# Calculating years between occurence of 1 in a column by group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have applied both code suggestions to my original data set to compare peace1 and peace2.

peace1:

```
d_muslim <- d_muslim %>% 
   mutate(last_conflict = lag(if_else(conflict == 1, year,NA),default = min(year) - 1),
   .by = country) %>%     
   tidyr::fill(last_conflict, .direction = "down") %>% 
   mutate(peace1 = year - last_conflict - 1)
```

peace2:

```
d_muslim <- d_muslim %>%
  mutate(helper = cumsum(lag(conflict, default = 1) == 1),.by = country) %>% 
  mutate(peace2 = year - first(year), .by = c(country, helper)) %>%
  select(-helper)
```

result:

| country | year | conflict | peace1 | peace2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Iran | 1946 | 0 | -73 | 0 |
| Iran | 1947 | 0 | -72 | 1 |
| Iran | 1948 | 0 | -71 | 2 |
| Iran | 1949 | 0 | -70 | 3 |
| Iran | 1950 | 0 | -69 | 4 |
| Iran | 1951 | 0 | -68 | 5 |
| Iran | 1952 | 0 | -67 | 6 |
| Iran | 1953 | 0 | -66 | 7 |
| Iran | 1954 | 0 | -65 | 8 |
| Iran | 1955 | 0 | -64 | 9 |
| Iran | 1956 | 0 | -63 | 10 |
| Iran | 1957 | 0 | -62 | 11 |
| Iran | 1958 | 0 | -61 | 12 |
| Iran | 1959 | 0 | -60 | 13 |
| Iran | 1960 | 0 | -59 | 14 |
| Iran | 1961 | 0 | -58 | 15 |
| Iran | 1962 | 0 | -57 | 16 |
| Iran | 1963 | 0 | -56 | 17 |
| Iran | 1964 | 0 | -55 | 18 |
| Iran | 1965 | 0 | -54 | 19 |
| Iran | 1966 | 1 | -1 | 0 |
| Iran | 1967 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Iran | 1968 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| Iran | 1969 | 0 | 2 | 3 |
| Iran | 1970 | 0 | 3 | 4 |
| Iran | 1971 | 0 | 4 | 5 |
| Iran | 1972 | 0 | 5 | 6 |
| Iran | 1973 | 0 | 6 | 7 |
| Iran | 1974 | 0 | 7 | 8 |
| Iran | 1975 | 0 | 8 | 9 |
| Iran | 1976 | 0 | 9 | 10 |
| Iran | 1977 | 0 | 10 | 11 |
| Iran | 1978 | 0 | 11 | 12 |
| Iran | 1979 | 1 | -1 | 0 |
| Iran | 1980 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Iran | 1981 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| Iran | 1982 | 0 | 2 | 3 |
| Iran | 1983 | 0 | 3 | 4 |
| Iran | 1984 | 0 | 4 | 5 |
| Iran | 1985 | 0 | 5 | 6 |
| Iran | 1986 | 1 | -1 | 0 |
| Iran | 1987 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Iran | 1988 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| Iran | 1989 | 0 | 2 | 3 |
| Iran | 1990 | 1 | -1 | 0 |
| Iran | 1991 | 1 | -1 | 0 |
| Iran | 1992 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Iran | 1993 | 1 | -1 | 0 |
| Iran | 1994 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Iran | 1995 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| Iran | 1996 | 1 | -1 | 0 |
| Iran | 1997 | 1 | -1 | 0 |
| Iran | 1998 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Iran | 1999 | 1 | -1 | 0 |
| Iran | 2000 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Iran | 2001 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| Iran | 2002 | 0 | 2 | 3 |
| Iran | 2003 | 0 | 3 | 4 |
| Iran | 2004 | 0 | 4 | 5 |
| Iran | 2005 | 1 | -1 | 0 |
| Iran | 2006 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Iran | 2007 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| Iran | 2008 | 0 | 2 | 3 |
| Iran | 2009 | 0 | 3 | 4 |
| Iran | 2010 | 0 | 4 | 5 |
| Iran | 2011 | 0 | 5 | 6 |
| Iran | 2012 | 0 | 6 | 7 |
| Iran | 2013 | 0 | 7 | 8 |
| Iran | 2014 | 0 | 8 | 9 |
| Iran | 2015 | 0 | 9 | 10 |
| Iran | 2016 | 1 | -1 | 0 |
| Iran | 2017 | 1 | -1 | 0 |
| Iran | 2018 | 1 | -1 | 0 |

Both codes do not fulfill my conditions.

1. the cumulation of the years of peace must extend into the year of conflict. And not be set to 0.
2. the year after a year of conflict must start with peace == 0. As the function of peace1 does correctly.

Comment: With your new data, it appears  that you say that a gap from 1985 to 1989 counts as 1 year of peace?

Comment: I have adjusted my post as recommended.

Regarding the missing observations, the problem has been solved. 

I create the variable Peace with the complete data set before deleting missing NAs, so that observation years are also deleted.

Comment: I ran the code you include in block 2 on the data you include in your question, and I get different results. Specifically, row 21 (`Iran,1966,1`) has `peace2=20`, not 0. ***However***, I can reproduce the problem when I specifically use `stats::lag` instead of `dplyr::lag`. You appear to have a conflict problem, you are somehow loading `stats` after `dplyr`. Call `dplyr::lag` specifically in that code block and you will get the desired `peace2`.

Comment: (I cannot reproduce your `peace1` in any way, unfortunately.)

Comment: After I change the code to use `dplyr::lag`, _both_ code blocks seem to work as you've specified.

Comment: Thank you. It was actually due to the package

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! both answers were correct :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your 15 should be 18, but otherwise ...

Using your "expected" as a starting point (for side-by-side comparison):

```r
quux |>
  mutate(
    last_conflict = lag(if_else(conflict == 1, year, NA), default = min(year) - 1),
    .by = country) |>
  tidyr::fill(last_conflict, .direction = "down") |>
  mutate(peace2 = year - last_conflict - 1)
#     country year conflict peace last_conflict peace2
# 1  country1 1990        1     0          1989      0
# 2  country1 1991        0     0          1990      0
# 3  country1 1992        0     1          1990      1
# 4  country1 1993        0     2          1990      2
# 5  country1 1994        1     3          1990      3
# 6  country1 1995        1     0          1994      0
# 7  country1 1996        0     0          1995      0
# 8  country1 1997        0     1          1995      1
# 9  country1 1998        0     2          1995      2
# 10 country1 1999        0     3          1995      3
# 11 country1 2014        0    15          1995     18
# 12 country2 1990        0     0          1989      0
# 13 country2 1991        1     1          1989      1
# 14 country2 1992        0     0          1991      0
# 15 country2 1995        1     3          1991      3
# 16 country2 1996        0     0          1995      0
# 17 country2 2000        1     4          1995      4
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(country = c("country1", "country1", "country1", "country1", "country1", "country1", "country1", "country1", "country1", "country1", "country1", "country2", "country2", "country2", "country2", "country2", "country2"), year = c(1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2014L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1995L, 1996L, 2000L), conflict = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), peace = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 15L, 0L,  1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

Comment: I think this is a bit more complicated than necessary. In any case, we can do ```df1 %>% mutate(peace = year - vctrs::vec_fill_missing(lag(if_else(conflict == 1, year, NA), default = min(year) - 1)) - 1, .by = country)``` to get the results in "one" go. Cheers.

Comment: You're replacing `tidyr::fill` with `vctrs::vec_fill_missing` (which I could have also done with `zoo::na.locf` inline), I'm not as well attuned to `vctrs::`, thanks for the note. This is code-golf better, certainly.

Comment: Yeah, my note about the complexity of this solution was not related to `tidyr` or `vctrs` (hence, starting the 2nd sentence with *in any case*). See my answer below for a simpler approach and most probably more efficient one.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `cumsum` along with `lag` to create a `helper` column for grouping and then simply find the difference between `year` and the `frist(year)` within each group;

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(helper = cumsum(lag(conflict, default = 1) == 1), .by = country) %>% 
  mutate(peace = year - first(year), .by = c(country, helper)) %>% 
  select(-helper)

#>     country year conflict peace
#> 1  country1 1990        1     0
#> 2  country1 1991        0     0
#> 3  country1 1992        0     1
#> 4  country1 1993        0     2
#> 5  country1 1994        1     3
#> 6  country1 1995        1     0
#> 7  country1 1996        0     0
#> 8  country1 1997        0     1
#> 9  country1 1998        0     2
#> 10 country1 1999        0     3
#> 11 country1 2014        0    18
#> 12 country2 1990        0     0
#> 13 country2 1991        1     1
#> 14 country2 1992        0     0
#> 15 country2 1995        1     3
#> 16 country2 1996        0     0
#> 17 country2 2000        1     4
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it did not work as expected. 1st Peace in a conflict year should also be counted as a peace year. 2. the peace value after a conflict year should assume the value 0. Only in the second peace year after the conflict will peace start with 1, since only in the second year after the conflict year would one year of peace be over.

Comment: @MalleOne please update your question with the desired output. The output you shared originally is matching what I have here. Cheers.